# switch WP url based on visitor country

Tags: redirect, geo

im a newbie here.

im trying to switch my WP url when a visitor from specific country is visted using following code. but currently its based on IPs, but I want to use a country code instead of list of many IPs. can anyone help me. really appreciated.

sample code im trying:

switch my WP url when a visitor from specific country

Comment: where do you imagine the country code coming from? the list of IPs is most likely based on a geolocation lookup. besides a static list, you can do the lookup yourself. if that is not what you want, please [edit] your question and add more details.

Comment: im posting it here to get help from others after I alread looked google to find a solution on this. what im looking is to find a way to replace the list of IPs with a geo country 2 digit code.

Comment: You need to provide moire information. as it stands, this question is unanswerable, and worst case you would get a lot of non-relevant answers. which programming language have you used (tag your question)? how have you determined the current list of IPs(if it is already a lookup - what do you expect to be able to improve)?

Comment: Also note that geo-blocking is not an exact science. neither is asking the browser which language it is using as default. You may not get the expected result